# Include Compass features without @import

Tags: sass, liquid, compass-sass

I'm working in [Liquid](http://liquidmarkup.org/), a templating language that has its own file extension. It is used not only in the HTML files, but CSS (or SCSS) as well. Problem is, `@import` doesn't work in a liquid file. Importing files like grids, Compass helpers, and variables is impossible.

Since you can't use `@import`, is there another way to include things like:

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "compass/css3/background-size";
```

Thanks

Comment: How is liquid being used in SCSS? It's a templating engine

Comment: Users define variables in their admin panel, and those values are passed into SCSS, which is converted into CSS.

The question remains, how can I cut out certain Compass helpers without manually going through the repo?